# Server with 3 public IP and iptables

Tags: iptables, ip-forwarding

I have a linux box with two NIC cards: eth0 and eth1.

In one card i have 3 public IP:

- eth0  = 10.10.10.1
- eth0:1= 10.10.10.2
- eth0:2= 10.10.10.3

In the other card I have one local IP

- eth1 = 192.9.200.1

I want to redirect all the wan traffic for 10.10.10.2 to the LAN 192.9.200.2 and the same for 10.10.10.3 to 192.9.200.3

I have tried with this rule but doesn't work

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 10.10.10.2 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.9.200.2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 10.10.10.3 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.9.200.3
```

IP forward is enabled in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: Can we get the output of service iptables status (or iptables -n -L if you are not on Red Hat / Centos).

Comment: It's not clear what it is you're trying to do. What do you mean by "redirect all the wan traffic"?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have forwarding allow rule you might have to explicitly allow it using:

```
-A FORWARD -s 10.10.10.2 -d 192.9.200.2 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.10.10.3 -d 192.9.200.2 -j ACCEPT
```